# Why does my NSTimer double decrement my timer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I have been staring at my code for hours now so I thought I might try coming here for some fresh eyes. I needed to create a timer so I used the code below to do that. The first line is where I create the timer and the second part is my decrementTime method. This is in Objective C for an IOS app. This is my first time posting on StackOverflow (I usually find the answer I am looking for), so please let me know of any unwritten rules that I am not following.

```
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(decrementTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)decrementTime{
       self.timeLeft--;
}
```

I'll add here where I invalidate the first timer

```
-(IBAction)infoClick:(id)sender{
       [_timer invalidate];   
}
```

Then here is info message, where I create another timer

```
- (void)hideInfoMessage {  
     _secondTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(decrementTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

clarification on my code: the order of events starts with my first code block (creating the timer). Then my second code block is called (invalidating the timer). then finally my third code block is called(making a new timer).

I know it is double incrementing because when I run the code I can visually see the timer double incrementing.

Comment: FWIW, no rules here are "unwritten" - have a look at the FAQ for everything you need to know (and more).  Good luck

Comment: How do you know it is being double decremented?

Comment: Trying adding `NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);` to your `decrementTime` so you can see every time that it's called

Comment: Based on your update code, you are creating two different timers and both point to the same selector. That would explain the double decrement.

Comment: @rmaddy I am sorry that I am still a little confused. When I invalidate the first timer doesn't it not exist anymore?

Comment: I guess I didn't notice that. Clarify the sequence of events in the posted code. And you still haven't clarified how you know that the timer is being double decremented.

Comment: Steve, for god's sake fix code formatting, my eyes hurt reading this code, my heart bleeds, I beg you, please.

Comment: sorry @Andy I'll fix it now (I'm just not used to using stackoverflows editing tools)

Comment: Haha! Thanks Steve! Don't worry, I was just joking, but it's really much easier to read tidy questions:-)

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to invoke the code that creates a timer twice. When you do that you actually have 2 timers running concurrently. Each one will decrement your value, so it will get decremented twice per second.

If you create a timer in your viewWillAppear method, for example, then you need to invalidate it in your viewWillDisappear method so you're sure you only have one running.

The same approach applies to other situations where you create a timer. You need to make sure you balance every call that creates a timer with a call that invalidates that timer.

If you use one of the scheduledTimer... methods, you can save a weak pointer to the timer. The run loop will retain it as long as it's running. When you invalidate it, the system run loop will release it and it will be deallocated. When that happens your weak pointer gets zeroed, so you don't even have to test it to see if it's valid/nil in your viewWillAppear method.

EDIT:

You need to instrument your code. In your infoClick method, is the variable `_timer` nil? What is it's address?

BTW, the target of an NSTimer is supposed to be a method that takes a single parameter, the timer itself. You should change your decrementTime method to look like this:

```
- (void) decrementTime: (NSTimer *) timer
{
  NSLog(@"In method decrementTime, timer = %X", (unsigned long) timer)
  self.timeLeft--;
}
```

Then look at your log and see if your decrementTime method is being called from 2 different timers (I would bet money that it is.)

You might also want to log the address of the timers you get back from your calls to scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval...

Comment: good answer.  also, the OP shows no terminal condition on the timer.  rather than decrement time left, compute a time in the future when the timer should end, save that and compare it to the current time when the timer fires.

Comment: thansk for the answer. yes i though that was a problem also. but the only time i create another timer is when i pause the game. i invalidate the first timer and the create a new one.

Comment: @SteveCohen just to be sure, put the line that invalidates _timer right before the line that assigns it.

Comment: State both ends of the problem explicitly, and provide the code in context. In what method do you create the timer, and in what method do you invalidate it? Are you positive that the calls are balanced? Try adding a log statement in both places and then look at the log. I offer a small wager that you're not always invalidating it before creating a new one.

Comment: thats what has been driving me insane. when I invalidate it again the timer stops.

Comment: To repeat: "State both ends of the problem explicitly, and provide the code in context" Show us all the code for both the method that creates the timer and the code that invalidates it, and explain when you think it's being called. You should also add log statements to both the method that creates the timer and the code that invalidates it.